# Design of an auditable system which doesn't require complex diffing on save

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, audit

We're currently trying to design a *simple* module for our system in order to make it auditable, but we're not sure on what the best strategy is. We want to try and nail it as early as possible because after the application goes live, migrating all the data to a different strategy could be a kerkuffle.

#### Strategy 1 – Our  current choice

The system we are currently experimenting with consists in creating a new record every time an update is made and when querying, simply get the ones with the latest `created_on` timestamp. In  the case that we have parent-child relationship and the child is to be updated, we would just update the child, not the parent. When querying those, we would apply the same strategy for every dependant relationship.

#### Strategy  2 – not so fond of it

Another strategy we have thought of would be to have two columns in each table, a `valid_from` and a `valid_to` timestamps. Every time we update a record, we would populate the `valid_to` to the previously valid record, and leave the current one with an empty value. We would follow a similar fetching strategy as the previous case.

To wrap up, I want to highlight that the main reason why we don't stick with *strategy 1* is because in order to save the data, it **requires us to go through a fairly complex diffing process which we're not fond of**. Every time the frontend calls our API with a new payload we fetch the latest aggregate (parent + children + grandchildren, etc), do a full diff and identify what to update.

So my question to you folks is, have you used any other auditing strategies your proud of and would like to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to consider next approach in addition to that you already have:

### Audit structure

For each table you want to audit, create another one for audit records with fields you want to audit plus field `revision` (and whatever another fields you want). For instance, if you have table "`Order`", create "`Order_aud`".

`Revision` field should be incrementing counter, it will make your audit records ordered. Also you can make it unique for each transaction if you want to be able to identify a set of objects that were saved in the same transaction.

### Updating data

Each time you update a record in auditable table - just create new record in corresponding audit table with the same data.

### Fetching data

Everything will be the same as it is right now, because you don't change origin tables at all.

Very similar approach is used in [Hibernate Envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/). It will let you to work with your audit independently of actual data, you can remove it, you can partitioning it, you can sharding it, you can archive it and you can easily disable it to make your application working as before.